# Set underline text for toogle bar hover button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can I set underline text when hovering a certain button on toggle bar?
I don't wan't to style all the buttons on toggle bar, but only the one I'm over.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Flex Style Browser](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html), this page will serve you to generate css code with all flex components.
I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<mx:Button id="btn" label="Mouse Over" 
mouseOver="btn.setStyle('textDecoration','underline')"
mouseOut="btn.setStyle('textDecoration','none')"
labelPlacement="left" useHandCursor="true"
buttonMode="true"/>`